# Using colwise() within an S3 method

Tags: r, plyr

I have a function `shift` defined as:

```
require(plyr)
shift <- function(x,...) {
    UseMethod("shift",x)
}
shift.default <- function(x,n=1,wrap=TRUE,pad=FALSE,...) {
    # innards
    return(0)
}
shift.data.frame <- colwise(shift.default)
```

It works just fine, until I put it in a package and try `R CMD check`.  Then I get a warning while checking S3 generic/method consistency.  It reports that shift.data.frame and shift don't agree:

```
shift(x,...)
shift.data.frame(df,...)
```

I assume this results from `x` and `df` not matching.  Any convenient way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps because your definition of shift.data.frame will not accept a triple dot instance?

Comment: Nah that was a typo but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Should that be `UseMethod("shift")`

Comment: @GSee The second argument to `UseMethod` just makes explicit whose class should be used to call the method.  If no argument is specified, it defaults to the first argument to the enclosing function.  I should note that the function works just fine, but compiling the package returns a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
shift.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  colwiseShift <- colwise(shift.default)
  colwiseShift(x, ...)
}
```